# Is it possible to return something when the condition inside the require fails?

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to return 0 inside a function in contract when the condition inside the `require` results to `false`?

Is it possible to return 0 inside a function in contract when the condition inside the `require` results to `false`?

```js
contract MyContract {
     function initialize() public payable returns (uint) {
        require(10 ** 15 < msg.value); //return 0 if this fails
        return 1; //otherwise return 1
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to provide a sample example of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `revert` and `if` statement coupled with custom error instead.
Check this out:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

error InvalidAmount (uint256 sent, uint256 minRequired);

contract C {
    uint32 public num;
    address public sender;

    function setVars(uint32 _num) public {
        if (_num < 5) {
            revert InvalidAmount({
                sent: _num,
                minRequired: 5
            });
        }
        num = _num;
    }
}
```

Focus on the `InvalidAmount` custom error at the top of the contract and the `revert` keyword, see how it is used and you should be able to do something similar for your use case.

By the way, using `revert` and custom errors saves more gas than using require.
For more understanding about the `revert` keyword, check [here](https://medium.com/blockchannel/the-use-of-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-and-the-new-revert-opcode-in-the-evm-1a3a7990e06e).